# Accessing Files with p5.js in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, p5.js

I'm a newbie getting started with p5.js and just got it working with Visual Studio Code and am having problems using any of the functions that access a file, be it image or text. My goal is to load a text file so I can parse it into vocabulary data.

Following the reference documents I added preload. You can see I also tried doing this with an image file and it produced the same results.

```
function preload(){
fileContents = loadStrings('defaultvocab.txt');
//img = loadImage('AthensDemocracy.jpg');
}
```

The result is this set of error messages
[image: error messages]
and a hang in the preload.

I'm not sure if it's a setting with VSCode or something I need to do in the JSON file it created, which I had to add the file to to get it to work also, so it's probably something to add in there but I'm not having much luck in finding it. Currently launch.json is this:

```
{

// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "file":"index.html"
    }
]
```

Please forgive the sad 90s web design and thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the webpage is still loading via the native file system path rather than the local web server (localhost:8080).

If you manually open [htts://localhost:8080](http://localhost:8080) in your browser does that run (is the web server actually running?)

Personally, I use Sam Levigne's [p5.vscode addon](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=samplavigne.p5-vscode):

1. install it
2. right click on your index.html
3. click **Open with Live Server**

I find the live coding (auto-reload on save) super useful, especially when prototyping.

Comment: Thank you! I got that and it works, though I still don't quite understand. I'd thought that web pages still worked in their local directories, like if I put it on a flash drive or something so not sure what's different here. Nothing is going on localhost:8080, that's just what VS Code created.

But if I put it on a web server it would work just like on Live Server?

And is there some way to link that to VS Code's run and debug options or does one just not use that?

Comment: Glad to hear that works. Feel free to vote up if it was helpful and check the green mark if is the solution to your problem. You are right that you can load html files from local directories, however, within the webpages, if you load external data, like your text file, you are actually performing an XML HTTP Request (XHR) you need a local webserver to load that data from. I can't remember 100% accurately, but I think Live Server should serve not just your index.html file, but the whole folder (e.g. http://localhost:5500/defaultvocab.txt). I'm not sure about the VS Code's run TBH.

Comment: For more info on p5.js and local web servers check out this page: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Local-server (Even though p5.vscode works, it's worth knowing on the long run)

Comment: Ha, I'm too new to vote but I'll come back here someday. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you ;) Hope the above makes sense. Good luck with the project!